# ReflectionException error on php artisan

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

Whenever I run artisan commands I get the following error message:

```
{"error":{"type":"ReflectionException","message":"Class OrdersModel does not exist","file":"\/home\/vagrant\/Omono\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Container\/Container.php","line":552}}
```

This only happens on my vagrant test server and not in production. I have tried running

```
composer dump-autoload
```

etc. And I have checked in composer.json and it has the models folder in there. I have also checked in vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php and it has my mapping:

```
'OrdersModel' => $baseDir . '/app/models/Orders.php',
```

I am unsure as to what else to try in rectifying this problem.

EDIT: Note that I do not have any problems with OrdersModel or any other classes on the actual larvel app.

EDIT2 **(important??)**: So, via the painstaking task of adding trace statements as verbose seems not to work, I have found that the problem lies when creating the service providers and comes down to the creating of a 'singleton' in the app. I did not write this code but it looks like there is an interface (OrderRepositoryInterface) and an implementation to map to it (DbOrderRepository). The file starts as follows

```
<?php namespace Omono\Repositories;

use OrdersModel as Order;
```

so for whatever reason this is where it looks for OrderModels and cannot find it. I am pretty certain there have been no problems with this module in the actual web app. So for some reason it can't find OrdersModel in this folder, **only when running artisan**.

EDIT3:

php -v gives:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'mongo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.5.12-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) (built: May 12 2014 13:48:43) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

I should also point out that everything runs fine when I access the website. OrdersModel does what it should do with no problems and I get no errors. This only happens when running the artisan command. Perhaps unrelated though is everytime I update my vagrant test server (the one with the problem) I need to run composer dumpautoload for a couple of classes to work.

Comment: Does Orders.php exist at 'app/models/'? Does that file contain a class called 'OrdersModel'?

Comment: Orders.php does exist, and contains OrdersModel class, which extends Eloquent.

Comment: Namespacing issue? What namespace is declared in Orders.php, and what is the root namespace for the application?

Comment: What happens if you type `php -v` from your command line? What version are you running?

Comment: No namespace is declared, so default namespace. It is the same as all the other models in the models folder (~30) as far as I can tell, although this model is a lot larger (~1500 lines).

Comment: I have added the output of php -v to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a lot of playing around I managed to solve this. This is a very specific problem but I will post my answer just in case anyone finds this question.

So following on from edit 2, I decided to comment out the line in the serviceprovider that references this class... fingers crossed... it worked. Kind of. It actually spat out an error because of the line     use Log;    in my code. Interesting. Let's remove that. It works. So I uncommented my class and in the class I noticed I also had use Log. In this case it isn't in the default namespace so this was correct, but I wasn't actually calling Log anywhere so, what the hell, might as well remove it. No dice. Then flicking between this class and an almost identical class. I noticed

```
use MyApp\Repositories\OrderRepositoryInterface;
```

Wait a minute. This isn't needed; as this is in the same namespace. I removed that line. Low and behold everything is fixed.

Summary; well... I don't know. I don't know how the error message meant this at all, but basically just check for things like these in your service providers. I have also read of a lot of people having problems because they used  instead of .